# How to check if a word is nice (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, performance

Definition of NICE is as below

A word is nice if it contains the same string as a proper prefix as well as a proper suffix. A proper prefix or suffix cannot be a long as the word itself.
For example:- 
manama is nice because it contains ma as a proper prefix as well as a proper suffix.So the output would be "NICE"

panama is not a nice word.Output in this case would be "NOT"

My solution working fine but it is taking too long for some of the test cases where length of input(word) is long.

```
public static String findNice(String word)  {
    if((word == null) || (word.length()==1))
        return "NOT";
    char[] charArr = word.toCharArray();
    //System.out.println(charArr.length);
    boolean flag = false;
    for(int i = (charArr.length)/2; i < charArr.length ;++i)    {
        if(charArr[0] == charArr[i])    {
            flag  = compareSubString(charArr,0,i);              
        }
    }
    if(flag)
        return "NICE";
    return "NOT";
}
public static boolean compareSubString(char[] seq, int ptr1, int ptr2)  {
    boolean flag = true;
    for(int i = ptr1,j = ptr2 ; j < seq.length  ;++i,++j)   {
        if(seq[i] != seq[j])    {
            flag = false;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

How to improve it further.

Comment: Working code is perhaps better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What if work like manamana is used, is this NICE or not??

Comment: I think you have to build **Suffix Tree** first and then analyze it.

Comment: @AshishJohn:- manamana is NICE

Comment: @notyou Thanks for the suggestion. Will take care of this in future.

Comment: @AditiSharma in the word "manamana" if we consider 'mana' as prefix & suffix then word lenth is 0. Is it nice??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding break statement as below:-

```
        if(seq[i] != seq[j])    {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to avoid two for loop

```
public static String findNice(String word) {
    int length = word.length();
    int haftLength = length / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i <= haftLength; i++) {
        if(getFirstWordByIndex(word, i).equalsIgnoreCase(getLastWordByIndex(word, i, length))) {
            return "NICE";
        }
    }
    return "NOT";
}

public static String getFirstWordByIndex(String str, int index) {
    return str.substring(0, index + 1);
}

public static String getLastWordByIndex(String str, int index, int length) {
    return str.substring(length - index-1, length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter and readable option could be to use `String.endswith`

```
public static String findNice(String word)  {
    String result = "NOT";
    for(int i = 0; i<word.length()/2;i++){
        String prefix = word.substring(0, i+1);
        if(word.endsWith(prefix)){
            result = "NICE! Prefix = "+prefix;
        }            
    }
    return result;
}
```